# Routing API v8 : How is 'baseDuration' estimated?

Tags: rest, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using Routing REST API V8 to collect travel time data. I understand that the difference between 'duration' and 'baseDuration' is traffic consideration. How is 'baseDuration' being calulated?

My guess is that it is some kind of free-flow travel time. In that case there must be an average speed along a given segment. Which goes back to the question, how is free-flow travel average speed determined?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are right **BaseDuration** is the time "without realtime traffic on the route" and **Duration** includes current traffic reduced speeds.

So answer to your question how free-flow travel average determined is based on map  long-term traffic pattern info, functional road class, speed category, country specific limits, etc

Answer (score 0):

Please note this situation:

You request a ROUTE A --> B

There is a major road closure and therefore HERE diverts you around adding 30m to the journey. This is good.

The **BaseDuration** is now calculated for the actual **given route** and NOT for the normal route, i.e. without road closures.

So you might get the same figure for BaseDuration and Duration as there is no traffic in the diverted route... it does not give you 30m as it gives you the information against the provided route.

OK,
Mark